# how can I use If-then-else in AMPL to write this contraint

Tags: ampl

I try to put this constraint at AMPL using logical conditional. Anyone could say a way to write this at AMPL

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I proposed this way and works

subject to c21 {k in CONVOY}:
sum {(i,j) in ARCOS:j=destino[k]} X[k,i,j] - sum{(j,h) in ARCOS:j=destino[k]}X[k,j,h]=1;

subject to c22 {k in CONVOY}:
sum {(i,j) in ARCOS: j=origen[k]} X[k,i,j] - sum{(j,h) in ARCOS:j=origen[k]}X[k,j,h]=-1;

subject to c23 {k in CONVOY, j in DESTINOS:j!=destino[k]&&j!=origen[k]}:
sum {(i,h) in ARCOS:h=j}X[k,i,j] - sum{(i,h) in ARCOS:i=j}X[k,j,h]=0;